# Attribute error: "module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'uniform' "

Tags: python, numpy

Here are some of the things I tried to make it work
I've tried searching for any file named *random.py* that I created (except for library files) and searched online for solutions like updating `numpy` but still can't find any decent solution. Here is my code:

```py
from numpy import random
import random

#from random import uniform

#inputs- i.e population

equation_inputs = [4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7]
 #number of weights 
num_weights = 6

sol_per_pop = 9

pop_size = (sol_per_pop,num_weights)
 #tuple of pop_size 

new_population = numpy.random.uniform(low=-4.0,high=4.0,size=pop_size)
```

The error message goes as follows

> > AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'uniform'

I tried importing `random` and also

`from numpy import random`

The `numpy.random.uniform` should actually return 9 lists each with 6 solutions

Comment: This is working for me with `import numpy` at the top.

Comment: On SO you'll see lots of examples of `import numpy as np`.  With that `np.random.uniform` works just fine.

Comment: hpaulj it doesnt work i tried all that

Comment: Could this be a version issue?

Comment: no it isn't the IDE is updated

Answer (score 0):

Just use `random.uniform` while importing the related class with an alias (using 'as')  or else just use `import numpy` while importing

An example for using alias is :

```
from numpy import random as np_random
```

Then utilize np_random.uniform()